# Antd - How to expand all tree items by default in Table with async data?

Tags: reactjs, antd

- The context: I want to create a **tree-like Table** using the component [<Table /> of antd](https://3x.ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand-children), **the data source is loaded asynchronously from the server**. And when the data is loaded, I want **all the nodes to be expanded**.
- Current situation: [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-banach-ulrzi?file=/index.js). There are 2 weird points remain:

1. Look at the images, when in the red rectangle the value is `null`, the nodes are expanded by default (which is what I want), but when the value in the rectangle is a clone dummy `<Table />`, the nodes are not expanded, why? Whether is it `null` nor `Table`, both would not be used anyway?
   [image][image]
2. When I click on the collapse button `[-]` near *Phòng ban kinh doanh* which is a level 2 node, why does it collapse all the tree? What is wrong with collapsing here?
   [image]

**Updated:** I have resolved the 2 concern [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-pine-eqrj3?file=/index.js). Now, how it make the nodes expanded by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why does the tree expands all by default when rendering the `Table` conditionally?

In React, `default[YourPropValue]` (for example `defaultValue`, `defaultChecked`,...) is a term frequently used to describe a prop value that only works when the component first mounts, this value is not used in subsequent renders. The `default[YourPropValue]`  is useful when you want an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) where the value is handled by the DOM element, not inside React code, and you want to initialize the value for the first time before React creates an element.

When you render conditionally based on the current data:

```
data ?
  <Table {...props} defaultExpandAllRows />
  :
  null
```

First there is no data, you return nothing. After the data is fetched, you start rendering the `Table`. This is the first time React sees you return the `Table` so it mounts with the `defaultExpandAllRows` set to `true` which works as expected.

The code below behaves differently because when you return the `Table` for the first time, you doesn't set `defaultExpandAllRows` (even if you set it, it doesn't matter because there is no data to expand). When the data is fetched, you also return the `Table` with the populated data. React reuses the last `Table` component and render for the second time, so the `defaultExpandAllRows` prop doesn't work anymore:

```
data ?
  <Table {...props} dataSource={data} />
  :
  <Table {...props} dataSource={[]} defaultExpandAllRows />
```

A simple solution to fix it is to tell React that the empty `Table` and the `Table` with the populated data is different so it can unmount and remount the component and make the default value applied correctly:

```
data ?
  <Table {...props} dataSource={data} defaultExpandAllRows />
  :
  <Table {...props} dataSource={[]} key='dummyTable' />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: OK so what I was missing was `key='dummyTable'`

Answer (score 0):

they say they only do on inital render https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/19166

so unfortunately the easiest way to do that with this limitation is
set initial state of data to null, and if there is no data don't render table

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-drake-2287i?file=/index.js

Comment: That seems to be what I've already done before posting the question...

Answer (score 0):

Incase if anyone looking for how to use `defaultExpandAllRows` in latest versions, try like this

`<Table ... expandable={{ defaultExpandAllRows: true }} />`

[Here's more info](https://ant.design/components/table#expandable)

Comment: You missed the point of the question. It used `defaultExpandAllRows` right from the beginning but the problem is the data comes after the first render.

Comment: Your question already have been answered, so this may not be the response you were looking for. Those seeking for a similar solution might find this helpful.